# Error with type alias

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to use a type alias to create a template with one argument, from a template with two arguments:

```
// forward declaration
template<int Id, typename MixtureManager> class MixtureBridge;

/**
 *  Specialization of the MixtureTraits for the Gaussian_sjk_ model
 **/
template<>
struct BridgeTraits<STK::Clust::Gaussian_sjk_>
{
   // ... some traits
};

template <typename MixtureManager>
using GaussianBridge_sjk_m = MixtureBridge<STK::Clust::Gaussian_sjk_, MixtureManager>;
```

I get the following error message:

```
mixt_GaussianBridges.h:65:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
```

What is wrong with my syntax ?

Note: I am working with gcc 4.6.3, on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template aliases are not supported in gcc 4.6 : https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html

upgrade your compiler to a more recent version.

Answer (score 1):

Alias-declarations are only supported from gcc 4.7 onwards

https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html